# Run async code from command line, node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that generates some test data and inserts it to a mongodb:

```
'use strict';
const CvFaker = require('./cv-faker');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('../models/cv_model.js');

module.exports.init = function(){
  var cvfaker = new CvFaker();
  cvfaker.genCvs(100);

  mongoose.model('cv').create(cvfaker.cvs, (err, createdCvs) => {
    if(err){
      console.log('something went wrong');
    }

  })
};
```

I want to execute this code from the command line:

```
node -e 'require("./create-mock-db").init()'
```

The function executes, but it does not wait for the function to complete since it is async. How do I make it wait for the function to complete?

This is not working either:

```
module.exports.init = function(cb){ ...
..
cb();

node -e 'require("./create-mock-db").init(function(){})'
```

Comment: In Javascript, functions do not wait for async operations to be done.  They just don't.  Usually, you use a completion callback to continue your logic there after the async operation is done.  If you describe what actual problem you're trying to solve by waiting, we can probably help you with alternatives.

Comment: Yes, but how do I add the callback when I'm executing from commandline?

Comment: Why not create your own script that loads this module and uses a completion callback as intended.  It's hard to write complicated code one line at a time on the console.  But, you could pass a callback to `.init()` that gets called when the async operation is done.

Comment: Since this code should not be in production, only in dev-mode, I don't want to expose it, hence I want to execute it from the command-line. I don't find any way to do so if you have async code.

Comment: It's nuts to do this on the console!  But, you can type a function into the console previously so its symbol is defined.  Then, pass that symbol as an argument to `.init()` as a callback function.

Comment: If you really don't want to write a script then don't do it in bash/sh (don't do it with `-e`). Do it in node instead: `node` then once the REPL loads `mockDB = require('./create-mock-db')` then after that returns `mockDB.init(...`

Comment: Remember, bash/sh is not the only command line that exist. You have `node` if you want to execute javascript. You have `mysql` if you want to run SQL commands on a database etc.

Comment: For me personally my projects always have a `./scripts` folder for commonly used developer scripts as per jfriend00's suggestion. Partly it is for quick testing during dev so I can call functions without opening my web browser etc.

Comment: The process should not exit until the event queue is empty. Async operations use the event queue. I don't see how adding a completion callback to `init()` would change this behavior and it's fairly trivial to verify this behavior (e.g., `node -e "setTimeout(() => console.log('done'), 5000)"`).

Answer (score 2):

*As this answer might come up for more people…*

```
// test.js
const request = require('request');
const rp = require('request-promise');

const demo = module.exports.demo = async function() {
  try {
    const res = await rp.post( {
      uri: 'https://httpbin.org/anything',
      body: { hi: 'there', },
    }, function (error, response, body) {
      return error ? error : body;
    } )
    console.log( res )
    return res;
  }
  catch ( e ) {
    console.error( e );
  }
};
```

Call it like this:

```
$ node -e 'require("./test").demo()'
```

**Sidenote:**

> it does not wait for the function to complete since it is async

It's not async. You might call asynchronous functions, but you are not treating them as such and not `await`ing any result.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `node` process will not exit until the event queue is empty. The [event loop](https://nodejs.org/uk/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) uses the event queue to make asynchronous execution possible.

It's pretty simple to verify that this is not an issue with executing asynchronous code.

```
node -e "setTimeout(() => console.log('done'), 5000)"
```

This example takes 5 seconds to run, as you would expect.

---

The problem with your code is the fact that you never establish a connection with the database. The `model.create` method doesn't do anything until there is a connection, therefor nothing ever gets queued and the process is free to exit.

This means your code needs to change to do two things:

1. Connect to the database so that the `model.create` method can execute.
2. Disconnect from the database when `model.create` is complete so the process is free to exit.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Kaiser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113456/18704147), if you are on Windows using cmd, the single/double quotes are important. Put the double quotes on the outside, i.e.

```
node -e "require('./test').demo()"
```